# Combining separate columns of time and date to one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in excel like this

[image]

I want to combine columns of Date and Time using the following code

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_excel('selfmade.xlsx')

df['new'] = df['Date'].map(str) + df['Time'].map(str)
print(df)
```

but it prints the results like this.

[image]

I want the last column in format like `2016-06-14 10:00:00`

What should I change in my code to get the desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), also is necessary convert `Time` column to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
```

If `dtype` of `Date` column is already `datetime`:

```
 df['new'] = df['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))
```

Comment: Not working,` TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()`

Comment: Maybe is necesary convert to `str`, check edited answer.